# How to change background color in Blender Internal?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

How can I change this render alpha background to a color?

[image]

I tried to change the "horizon color," but it didn't work.

Comment: Render Tab > Shading > Alpha > set it to Sky; Then you should be able to change the background via the _Horizon Color_ in the _World Tab_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Switch the background alpha from transparent to sky:

[image]

---

[image]